# How to access directly to the last argument of a function in ash?

Tags: linux, shell, ash

To access to the first argument of a function, I use

```
func() { echo $1; }
```

How to access directly to the last argument of a function in ash?

I do not want to use loops neither functions or complicated commands

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$($#)`.

`$#` is the number of arguments (which is equal to the index of the last argument), so `$($#)` is the last argument.

Comment: If you have to enter 25 space characters before your final question mark, that's a very good indication that your answer is not an answer. Use words to explain what you mean by those 4 characters.

Comment: There's nothing much to explain : $# is the number of arguments, which is the index of the last argument, so $($#) is the last argument.

Comment: This is wrong.  Round parentheses are used for command substitution.  In theory, `${$#}` with curly brackets could work, but it doesn't without additional indirection (so basically `eval \${$#}` with all the usual caveats against `eval`).